# How to replace a function in php?

Tags: php, function, replace

I have a PHP file with this content bellow:
abc.php

```
echo 'echo echo echo';
echo $x.'echo echo echo'.str_replace($x, 'abc', $y);
echo number_format(1234567); echo "echo echo echo";
```

I want to replace "echo" function in abc.php to "$b .=" and the result after replace will be:

```
$b .= 'echo echo echo';
$b .= $x.'echo echo echo'.str_replace($x, 'abc', $y);
$b .= number_format(1234567); echo "echo echo echo";
```

How can I do this? Please help me, thank you so much!

Note: I read abc.php by file_get_contents (the result is a string). After that, I replace "echo" to "b .=" and then use "eval" to execute.

Comment: Did you intentionally exclude the last `echo`, second statement, last line? If you did (*and I highly advise against this*) you could `preg_replace()` on the source with `#^(echo)#` to `$b .=` - based on the likelihood of you wanting output buffering, I'd favor any answer here.

Comment: I would just do it manually to ensure I don't make a mistake. But depending on what you are doing, you could consider output buffering.

Comment: Why don't you just edit the PHP file?

Comment: Do you want to [override](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) `echo`, or do you want to Find&Replace `echo` with `$b .=` in a file?

Comment: Is that *actually* what you want to do, or is this an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Suggesting a function from an ancient and unmaintained PECL package (a debugger even) sounds dangerous...

Comment: @Piskvor just trying to figure out what OP means, it wasn't a suggestion.

Comment: I read abc.php by file_get_contents (the result is a string). After that, I replace "echo" to "b .=" and then use "eval" to execute.

But I don't know how to replace.

Answer (score 8):

If you can't modify the code, you can start output buffering and save the output in a variable:

```
ob_start();
include('abc.php');
$b = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 3):

### If abc.php is executed as PHP

You can use output buffering for this if this file (`abc.php`) is accessed via `include` or `require`. See the [manual page for `ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start).

```
$file_path = '/my/file/path/abc.php';
ob_start();
require $file_path;
$b .= ob_get_clean();
```

For more information about `ob_get_clean()` see [the man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

### If abc.php is pulled in as plain text for pre-processing

Or you could use a simple string replace if you are using `file_get_contents()` instead of `require` or `include` to access `abc.php`:

```
$file_path = '/my/file/path/abc.php';
$file_contents_string = file_get_contents($file_path);
$replaced_string = str_replace('echo ', '$b .= ', $file_contents_string);
file_put_contents($file_path);
```

This replacement will replace all instances of `echo` so it is pretty greedy, which may end up replacing more than you initially expect. This can be mitigated through using `preg_replace()` or a combination of `substr()` and `strpos()`.

Comment: this replacement is dangerous, as if the text contains 'echo' (as in the example, it will be replaced as well); Also echo supports many operands: echo 'a', 'b', 'c'; which will be invalid syntax if you simply replace it with assignment.

Comment: Yes, echo can handle multiple parameters, but this is rarely done and not mentioned in the question sample code at all. In fact the coding style guidelines I wrote for my team ban this use of `echo` and use string concatenation instead to get around the problem of an `echo` easily becoming a string assigned to a variable during refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `echo() is not actually a function` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php ; as for dynamically replacing one function with another, that's normally not possible in PHP (you'd get a `Cannot redeclare function` error).

As for the *probable* question that you didn't ask - "how do I get this into a variable, so it's not echoed out directly" (and no, thinking doesn't count):

see the Output Buffering functions - e.g. `ob_get_clean()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: Well, you shouldn't, but http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php - Wouldn't work with `echo` anyways though.

Comment: @Bracketworks: PECL package `runkit`: version 0.9, status beta, last release 2006-06-06 ? I'd ... hesitate ... to use that.

Comment: Oh I agree, however it exists. It's been succeeded by something at this point, hasn't it?

Comment: @Bracketworks: It was *supposed* to be replaced by the next version of classkit (like PHP6 was supposed...nevermind, let's not go there), but *that* was abandoned even earlier. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.classkit.php and http://pecl.php.net/package/classkit

Comment: I thought it was `classkit`. Also -- PHP 6 is going to be great! When do you think it'll come out? Next month? Is it in alpha? Are there binaries available? I bought all the books! Herp! Derp! Thbbb! -- Ah well, 5.4 will do... **for now**.

Answer (score 0):

Why does this keep happening? People have a problem A, and come up with a solution B that's unneccesarily difficult or weird or not following any standard practices, which raises problem C. Then they only ask for a solution for problem C.

Solve problem A using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).